# Django - Query models where id equals attribute on python list

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-filter

I need to query all models where the ID matches the 'id' attribute of JSON array, something like that:

I have 3 saved model objects with respective ID's:

```
ID 1
ID 3
ID 4
```

I have a JSON array like that:

```
[{'id' : 1}, {'id' : 2}, {'id' : 5}]
```

I want to filter in that way:

```
model.objects.filter('Objects by ID that is not listed in the JSON array')
```

The result of the filter should be a list with models objects that the ID is not in the JSON:

```
result = [model_pk=3, model_pk=4]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) method to achieve that:

```
ids = [i['id'] for i in json_array]
qs = model.objects.exclude(id__in=ids)
```